# javascript onclick & ontouch

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript and am wondering if someone can show me how the 'ontouch' function is supposed to be added in a correct way. 
I have this html onclick function, that works fine in browswers, but not on iPhone:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:12px; color: #f2f2f2;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
```

And the javascript part:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

And searching on here people suggests that something like this is added:

```
// First we check if you support touch, otherwise it's click:
let touchEvent = 'ontouchstart' in window ? 'touchstart' : 'click';

// Then we bind via thát event. This way we only bind one event, instead of the two as below
document.getElementById('hbs').addEventListener(touchEvent, someFunction);

// or if you use jQuery:
$('#hbs').on(touchEvent, someFunction);
```

But what goes where and how?

Comment: And have you tried the suggestion and saw it works? I mean it's not so clear if you are asking the correct way or the gebuinity of the last code block you shared.

Comment: It had 30 upvotes, so it obviously works for some people. But I am asking to learn. I would like to have the third code explained. What goes where in the javascript code and why. That's what I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:12px; color: #f2f2f2;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {

  // the code that need to be executed when button is clicked

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if the button is not to be clicked, but to be touched? That is my actual questions. How to make a button both clickable/touchable.

Comment: buttons are always both clickable and touchable. A onclick function works both with touch-screens and left-clicks.

Comment: Wow. I just had a friend try and you are right. My phone is apparently broken, and Google told me another function existed that I would have to use. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you.

```
$('myTopnav').bind('touchstart' , function(e) { 
   // get x,y code
   var touch = e.touches[0];
   var y = touch.pageY;
   var x = touch.pageX;

   // pass to function down(x,y);
   down(x,y);
});

function down(x,y) {
   // do something with x,y
}
```